# How do I push an event to the GTM datalayer for when a HubSpot form has loaded on my page?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, hubspot

I have created a form listener that is listening for when a form has loaded on the page. This is the script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
   if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormReady') {
       window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'hubspot-form-ready',
        'hs-form-guid': event.data.id
      });
    }
});
</script>
```

I have a similar script that works for 'onFormSubmitted' just fine, but I can't seem to get anything to work for 'onFormReady'.

My end goal is to listen for the form to make sure it has loaded on the page, then use that event to manipulate the form (e.g. add cookie values to hidden form fields). I just have to make sure the form is loaded first.

Has anyone done anything similar to this?

Comment: Did you put your form listener code in the HTML of the page or as a custom HTML Tag in the GTM? If it's the latter, the event might have already fired when the GTM initialises.

Comment: @ptts I added it as a custom HTML Tag in GTM. Would you recommend putting it in the HTML of the page?

Comment: If it is in fact a timing issue (as in, the event has already been emitted by the time GTM sets up the event listener), you would have to put in the HTML of the page, yes. And there as well it would need to execute as early as possible (before the event is emitted).